# Use bluebird for mongoose, got ".bind is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bluebird

I use [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) for [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/):

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

And I want to use [Promise.bind](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html) to share variable in the promise chain:

```
function getAutherOfBook(name)
{
    return Book.findOne(
        {
            name: name
        }, "-_id auther")
        .then(doc =>
        {
            return doc.auther;
        });
};


function geNationalityOfAuther(name)
{
    return Auther.findOne(
        {
            name: name
        }, "-_id nationality")
        .then(doc =>
        {
            return doc.nationality;
        });
};


getAutherOfBook("The Kite Runner")
    .bind({})
    .then(auther =>
    {
        this.auther = auther;
        return geNationalityOfAuther(auther);
    })
    .then(nationality =>
    {
        console.log("auther: ", this.auther);
        console.log("nationality: ", nationality);
    })
    .bind()
```

But I got the error: **getAutherOfBook(...).bind is not a function**

Maybe bluebird is not working for mongoose?

Comment: What version of mongoose are you running?  Setting the `mongoose.Promise` property requires v4.1.0.

Comment: I use mongoose 4.7.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are having is that mongoose queries does not return full fledge promises -- directly quoting http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html (v4.7.6)

```
// A query is not a fully-fledged promise, but it does have a `.then()`.
query.then(function (doc) {
  // use doc
});

// `.exec()` gives you a fully-fledged promise
var promise = query.exec();
assert.ok(promise instanceof require('mpromise'));
```

In other words, the `then` function is syntax sugar and not a `promise` which is why the `bind` and other promise functions does not work.

To make it work, you either wrap it up in a full promise or use the `exec` function as suggested in the docs

Comment: Using exec does help. Thank you