# Error on Bluebird spread function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

When I start so code

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
const mongodb = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongodb'));
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(url).then((db) => {
    return Promise.all([new WorkerService(db)]);
}).spread((workerService) => (
    Promise.all([new WorkerRouter(workerService)])
)).spread((workerRouter) => {
   app.use('/worker', workerRouter);
}).then(() => {
    httpServer.start(config.get('server.port'));
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
   httpServer.finish();
```

});

I see so error

```
}).spread(function (workerService) {
   ^

TypeError: MongoClient.connect(...).then(...).spread is not a function
```

Please help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently ` MongoClient.connect(...).then(...)` is not a Bluebird promise.  Why are you using `.spread()` for a single parameter anyway?  And, why are you using `Promise.all()` and passing it an array of length 1?  Both of those are odd.

Comment: Does `new WorkerRouter(workerService)` return a promise?  It doesn't seem like it would so I don't know why you're passing that to `Promise.all()`.  `Promise.all()` expects an array of promises.

Comment: I doubt "new *AnythingOtherThanPromise*" would return a Promise

Comment: Since, it looks like you're new here, let me explain a bit about stack overflow.  We're trying to help you, but you seem to have posted and then disappeared.  That's not really how stack overflow works.  This places is much more interactive than a typical internet forum where you might post and then come back the next day to see what replies you got.  If you do that here and fail to interact with people asking you questions, your question may just get downvoted for being non-responsive or unclear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517477/use-bluebird-for-mongoose-got-bind-is-not-a-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934223/object-promise-has-no-method-catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several things wrong here:

The root cause here is that `MongoClient.connect(...).then(...)` is not returning a Bluebird promise, thus, there is no `.spread()` method.  When you promisify an interface with Bluebird, it does NOT change the existing methods at all.  Instead, it adds new methods with the "Async" suffix on it.

So, unless you've somehow told Mongo to create only Bluebird promises, then

```
`MongoClient.connect(...).then(...)`
```

will just be returning whatever kind of promise Mongo has built in.  You will need to use the new promisified methods:

```
MongoClient.connectAsync(...).then(...).spread(...)
```

---

Some other issues I see in your code:

1) `Promise.all()` expects you to pass it an array of promises.  But when you do this:  `Promise.all([new WorkerRouter(workerService)])`, you're passing it an array of a single object which unless that object is a promise itself, is just wrong.

2) In this code:

```
}).spread((workerService) => (
    Promise.all([new WorkerRouter(workerService)])
))
```

you need to return the resulting promise in order to link it into the chain:

```
}).spread((workerService) => (
    return Promise.all([new WorkerRouter(workerService)])
))
```

3) But, there's no reason to use `Promise.all()` on a single element array.  If it was a promise, then just return it.

4) It also looks like you're trying to use promises for different steps of synchronous code too.  Besides just complicating the heck out of things, there's just no reason to do that as this:

```
}).spread((workerService) => (
    Promise.all([new WorkerRouter(workerService)])    
)).spread((workerRouter) => {
   app.use('/worker', workerRouter);
}).then(() => {
    httpServer.start(config.get('server.port'));
})...
```

can be combined to this:

```
)).spread((workerService) => {
    app.use('/worker', new WorkerRouter(workerService));
    httpServer.start(config.get('server.port'));
})...
```

And, can probably be condensed even further since `new WorkerService(db)` probably also doesn't return a promise.

5) And, then we can't really tell why you're even attempting to use `.spread()` in the first place.  It is useful only when you have an array of results that you want to turn into multiple named arguments, but you don't need to have an array of results (since there was no reason to use `Promise.all()` with a single item and in modern version of node.js, there's really no reason to use `.spread()` any more because you can use ES6 destructing of an array function argument to accomplish the same thing with the regular `.then()`.

---

I don't claim to follow exactly what you're trying to do with every line, but you may be able to do this:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
const mongodb = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongodb'));
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
MongoClient.connectAsync(url).then((db) => {
    let service = new WorkerService(db);
    app.use('/worker', new WorkerRouter(service));
    // since httpServer.start() is async and there's no promise returning here,
    // this promise chain will not wait for the server to start
    httpServer.start(config.get('server.port'));
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    httpServer.finish();
});
```